# Video Game Score Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-physics

Currently I am creating a Javascript game. I have successfully created all the game pieces and how my game's basic functions should work. However, I am having 2 issues that I can't seem to solve, and I've looked for a few weeks now trying to figure out how to do it. I can't figure out how to get the game to result in a gameover if my player gets pushed of falls off screen. Also, I am unsure on how I can get the score to continously increase for as long as the player is still "alive". If anyone can either demonstrate how to do these things or point me in the direction of a tutorial or article on how to do it it would be very helpful.

```js
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();


const seeded = (() => {
  var seed = 1;
  return {
    max: 2576436549074795,
    reseed(s) {
      seed = s
    },
    random() {
      return seed = ((8765432352450986 * seed) + 8507698654323524) % this.max
    },
  }
})();
const randSeed = (seed) => seeded.reseed(seed);
const randSI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seeded.random() % (max - min)) + min;
const randS = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seeded.random() / seeded.max) * (max - min) + min;

randSeed(100); // seed the random generators 


function Player(color, keymap, x) {
  this.x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? 1 : x;
  this.y = 7;
  this.width = 15;
  this.height = 15;
  this.speed = 10;
  this.velX = 0;
  this.velY = 0;
  this.jumping = false;

  this.keymap = {}
  for (let key in keymap) {
    switch (keymap[key]) {
      case 'jump':
        this.keymap[key] = this.jump
        break;
      case 'left':
        this.keymap[key] = this.moveLeft
        break;
      case 'right':
        this.keymap[key] = this.moveRight
        break;
    }
  }
  this.color = color;
} // Player()

Player.prototype.jump = function() {
  if (!this.jumping) {
    this.jumping = true;
    this.velY = -this.speed * 1.5;
  }
}
Player.prototype.moveRight = function() {
  if (this.velX < this.speed) {
    this.velX++;
  }
}
Player.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
  if (this.velX > -this.speed) {
    this.velX--;
  }
}
// Globals
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = 700,
  height = 600,
  keys = [],
  friction = .9,
  gravity = .9;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Set up players
var players = [];
players.push(new Player('purple', {
  32: 'jump',
  37: 'left',
  38: 'jump',
  39: 'right'
}))
/*players.push(new Player('yellow', {
   56: 'jump',
   52: 'left',
   54: 'right'
}, width-25))*/
players.push(new Player('blue', {
   87: 'jump',
   65: 'left',
   68: 'right'
}, (width-25)/2))

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  addPlatformsToBottom(); // will add platforms if needed
  drawPlatforms();
  players.forEach(player => {
    // check player-specific keys
    for (let i in player.keymap) {
      if (keys[i] && typeof player.keymap[i] === 'function')
        player.keymap[i].bind(player)();
    }

    player.velX *= friction;

    player.velY += gravity;

    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;

    if (player.x >= width - player.width) {
      player.x = width - player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {
      player.x = 0;
    }

    if (player.y >= height - player.height) {
      player.y = height - player.height;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.velY = 0;
    }
    testPlayerForPlatforms(player);

    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  }) // player.forEach
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  //  console.log(e.keyCode);
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  update();
});

function testPlayerForPlatforms(player) {
  player.hitPlatform = false; // reset platform hit flag
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    var p = platforms[i];
    if (p.active) {
      testPlayer(player, p);
      if (player.hitPlatform) {
        break; // stop search as player has hit a platform
      }
    }
  }
}


function drawPlatforms() { // draws all platforms and move up
  platformInfo.lastPlatformY += platformInfo.speed;
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    var p = platforms[i];
    if (p.active) {
      p.yPos += platformInfo.speed;
      if (p.yPos + p.height < 0) { // platform above top 
        p.active = false; // turn it off
      } else {
        p.draw();
      }
    }
  }
}

function addPlatformsToBottom() {
  while (platformInfo.lastPlatformY < ctx.canvas.height) {
    generateLevel();
  }
}

// some constants and vars to control random generation of platforms
const platformInfo = {
  speed: -2.5,
  height: 8, // platform height
  minLength: 100, // in pixels
  maxLength: 300,
  vertSpacing: 100, // distance between platforms
  minHorSpacing: 50, // should be larger than player
  maxHorSpacing: 80,
  lastPlatformY: 100, // y position of last platform created
  maxHoleCount: 3,
  color: "#FFF",
}
// array object holds platforms
const platforms = [];

// a platform template object that will be used to create platforms from
const platform = {
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  yPos: 0,
  height: 0, // thickness
  active: false, // true if platform in use
  color: "#F84",
  draw() { // function to draw the platform
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.left, this.yPos, this.right - this.left, this.height);
  },
  init(left, right, yPos) { // function to initialize 
    // alias to save typing.
    const pI = platformInfo
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.height = pI.height;
    this.color = pI.color;
    this.active = true;
  },
}
// function adds platforms to array. If no inactive platforms a
// new one is created
function addPlatform() {
  var platform;
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    if (!platforms[i].active) { // is the platform inactive
      platform = platforms[i];
      break; // stop searching
    }
  }
  if (!platform) { // if no inactive platform then create a new one
    platform = createPlatform();
    platforms.push(platform);
  }
  return platform;
}

// a function to create a platform object
function createPlatform(customProps = {}) { // custom props can be used to modify the
  // platform in future. For now it just defaults to empty 
  return Object.assign({}, platform, customProps);
}
// creates a set of platforms for a single level
function generateLevel() {
  var numHoles = randSI(1, platformInfo.maxHoleCount);
  var spacing = ctx.canvas.width / (numHoles); // get spacing
  var ypos = platformInfo.lastPlatformY;
  platformInfo.lastPlatformY += platformInfo.vertSpacing;
  var left = 0; // the starting left edge
  for (var i = 1; i <= numHoles; i++) { // create numHoles
    var platform = addPlatform();
    var holeOffset = randSI(-spacing, 0);
    platform.init(left, spacing * i + holeOffset, ypos);
    left = spacing * i + holeOffset + randSI(platformInfo.minHorSpacing, platformInfo.maxHorSpacing);
  }
  // add the last platform
  platform = addPlatform();
  platform.init(left, ctx.canvas.width, ypos);
}



function testPlayer(player, platform) {
  var p, pl; // p for player, pl for platform
  p = player;
  pl = platform;
  // is the player above or below platform
  if (!(p.x + p.width < pl.left || p.x > pl.right)) { // yes
    if (p.velY > 0 && p.y < pl.yPos) { // is player moving down and above platform
      if (p.y + p.height > pl.yPos) { //is bottom of player below top of platform
        // must have hit platform
        p.jumping = false;
        p.y = pl.yPos - p.height; // move player so that it is on the platform
        p.velY = 0;
        p.hitPlatform = true; // flag a platform has been hit
      }
    } else if (p.y + p.height > pl.yPos + pl.height) { // player must be moving up so check if below platform
      if (p.y < pl.yPos + pl.height) { // is top of player above bottom of platform
        // must have hit head on platform
        p.velY = 0;
        p.y = pl.yPos + pl.height;
        p.jumping = false;
        p.hitPlatform = true; // flag a platform has been hit
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#score {
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  
}
```

```html
0<html>

<head>
  <title>Square Stairs™</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000">
  <div id="score">SCORE:</div>
  <br><br><br> <!-- line breaks to move canvas away from SO title bar that gets in the way when switching to full page mode -->
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border:3px solid #fff"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code as it stands currently. I made on the website[CodePen](https://codepen.io/MilkyBOii/pen/oZXmzX?editors=1000)and this is my original code. I have nothing to do with Unity or any other coding platform so if you have any information on how to solve this it has to be able to run on the CodePen website. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've added code to your code, look for `////////////////////`

I added the following to your source code:

1. Added the functions `checkPlayerBounds(player)` and `addToScore(x)`

   - `checkPlayerBounds(player)` checks if `player` has been pushed/fell off the screen.

     - *Note: You need to add more functionality here to have the Game Over do what you want.*
   - `addToScore(x)` increases the `score` variable and the *Score* HTML element if `scoreShouldUpdate` is true.
2. Added global variables `updates`, `score`, and `scoreShouldUpdate`.

   - `updates` keeps track of how many times the `update()` function has been called.
   - `score` keeps track of the games score.
3. Added code inside your `update()` function.

   - The first bit keeps adding to the score, but only after the game has been updated a specified amount of times.
   - The next bit calls the `checkPlayerBounds` function on every player.

This all works, the only problem is that the player starts off/right on the edge of the screen, so the score won't update until that is changed in your project.

```js
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();


const seeded = (() => {
  var seed = 1;
  return {
    max: 2576436549074795,
    reseed(s) {
      seed = s
    },
    random() {
      return seed = ((8765432352450986 * seed) + 8507698654323524) % this.max
    },
  }
})();
const randSeed = (seed) => seeded.reseed(seed);
const randSI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seeded.random() % (max - min)) + min;
const randS = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (seeded.random() / seeded.max) * (max - min) + min;

randSeed(100); // seed the random generators 

///////////////////////////
// This function increases the score by 'x' amount.
///////////////////////////
function addToScore(x){
    if(scoreShouldUpdate){
        score += x;
        var scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
        scoreElement.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
    }
}

function checkPlayerBounds(player){
    if(player.y >= 0){
         scoreShouldUpdate = false;
         // Insert game over stuff here.
    }
        
}

function Player(color, keymap, x) {
  this.x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? 1 : x;
  this.y = 7;
  this.width = 15;
  this.height = 15;
  this.speed = 10;
  this.velX = 0;
  this.velY = 0;
  this.jumping = false;

  this.keymap = {}
  for (let key in keymap) {
    switch (keymap[key]) {
      case 'jump':
        this.keymap[key] = this.jump
        break;
      case 'left':
        this.keymap[key] = this.moveLeft
        break;
      case 'right':
        this.keymap[key] = this.moveRight
        break;
    }
  }
  this.color = color;
} // Player()

Player.prototype.jump = function() {
  if (!this.jumping) {
    this.jumping = true;
    this.velY = -this.speed * 1.5;
  }
}
Player.prototype.moveRight = function() {
  if (this.velX < this.speed) {
    this.velX++;
  }
}
Player.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
  if (this.velX > -this.speed) {
    this.velX--;
  }
}
// Globals
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = 700,
  height = 600,
  keys = [],
  friction = .9,
  gravity = .9;

//////////////////////////////
//New variables for score increase
//////////////////////////////
var updates = 0;
var score = 0;
var scoreShouldUpdate = true;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Set up players
var players = [];
players.push(new Player('purple', {
  32: 'jump',
  37: 'left',
  38: 'jump',
  39: 'right'
}))
/*players.push(new Player('yellow', {
   56: 'jump',
   52: 'left',
   54: 'right'
}, width-25))*/
players.push(new Player('blue', {
   87: 'jump',
   65: 'left',
   68: 'right'
}, (width-25)/2))

function update() {

  /////////////////////////////////////
  // You can change the '5' to something else to change the rate of which score is increased.
  /////////////////////////////////////
  if(updates == 5){
      updates = 0;
      addToScore(1);
  }
  updates++;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  addPlatformsToBottom(); // will add platforms if needed
  drawPlatforms();
  players.forEach(player => {
    // check player-specific keys
    for (let i in player.keymap) {
      if (keys[i] && typeof player.keymap[i] === 'function')
        player.keymap[i].bind(player)();
    }

    player.velX *= friction;

    player.velY += gravity;

    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;

    if (player.x >= width - player.width) {
      player.x = width - player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {
      player.x = 0;
    }

    if (player.y >= height - player.height) {
      player.y = height - player.height;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.velY = 0;
    }
    testPlayerForPlatforms(player);

    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

    //My code
    checkPlayerBounds(player);

  }) // player.forEach
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  //  console.log(e.keyCode);
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  update();
});

function testPlayerForPlatforms(player) {
  player.hitPlatform = false; // reset platform hit flag
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    var p = platforms[i];
    if (p.active) {
      testPlayer(player, p);
      if (player.hitPlatform) {
        break; // stop search as player has hit a platform
      }
    }
  }
}


function drawPlatforms() { // draws all platforms and move up
  platformInfo.lastPlatformY += platformInfo.speed;
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    var p = platforms[i];
    if (p.active) {
      p.yPos += platformInfo.speed;
      if (p.yPos + p.height < 0) { // platform above top 
        p.active = false; // turn it off
      } else {
        p.draw();
      }
    }
  }
}

function addPlatformsToBottom() {
  while (platformInfo.lastPlatformY < ctx.canvas.height) {
    generateLevel();
  }
}

// some constants and vars to control random generation of platforms
const platformInfo = {
  speed: -2.5,
  height: 8, // platform height
  minLength: 100, // in pixels
  maxLength: 300,
  vertSpacing: 100, // distance between platforms
  minHorSpacing: 50, // should be larger than player
  maxHorSpacing: 80,
  lastPlatformY: 100, // y position of last platform created
  maxHoleCount: 3,
  color: "#FFF",
}
// array object holds platforms
const platforms = [];

// a platform template object that will be used to create platforms from
const platform = {
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  yPos: 0,
  height: 0, // thickness
  active: false, // true if platform in use
  color: "#F84",
  draw() { // function to draw the platform
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.left, this.yPos, this.right - this.left, this.height);
  },
  init(left, right, yPos) { // function to initialize 
    // alias to save typing.
    const pI = platformInfo
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.height = pI.height;
    this.color = pI.color;
    this.active = true;
  },
}
// function adds platforms to array. If no inactive platforms a
// new one is created
function addPlatform() {
  var platform;
  for (var i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
    if (!platforms[i].active) { // is the platform inactive
      platform = platforms[i];
      break; // stop searching
    }
  }
  if (!platform) { // if no inactive platform then create a new one
    platform = createPlatform();
    platforms.push(platform);
  }
  return platform;
}

// a function to create a platform object
function createPlatform(customProps = {}) { // custom props can be used to modify the
  // platform in future. For now it just defaults to empty 
  return Object.assign({}, platform, customProps);
}
// creates a set of platforms for a single level
function generateLevel() {
  var numHoles = randSI(1, platformInfo.maxHoleCount);
  var spacing = ctx.canvas.width / (numHoles); // get spacing
  var ypos = platformInfo.lastPlatformY;
  platformInfo.lastPlatformY += platformInfo.vertSpacing;
  var left = 0; // the starting left edge
  for (var i = 1; i <= numHoles; i++) { // create numHoles
    var platform = addPlatform();
    var holeOffset = randSI(-spacing, 0);
    platform.init(left, spacing * i + holeOffset, ypos);
    left = spacing * i + holeOffset + randSI(platformInfo.minHorSpacing, platformInfo.maxHorSpacing);
  }
  // add the last platform
  platform = addPlatform();
  platform.init(left, ctx.canvas.width, ypos);
}



function testPlayer(player, platform) {
  var p, pl; // p for player, pl for platform
  p = player;
  pl = platform;
  // is the player above or below platform
  if (!(p.x + p.width < pl.left || p.x > pl.right)) { // yes
    if (p.velY > 0 && p.y < pl.yPos) { // is player moving down and above platform
      if (p.y + p.height > pl.yPos) { //is bottom of player below top of platform
        // must have hit platform
        p.jumping = false;
        p.y = pl.yPos - p.height; // move player so that it is on the platform
        p.velY = 0;
        p.hitPlatform = true; // flag a platform has been hit
      }
    } else if (p.y + p.height > pl.yPos + pl.height) { // player must be moving up so check if below platform
      if (p.y < pl.yPos + pl.height) { // is top of player above bottom of platform
        // must have hit head on platform
        p.velY = 0;
        p.y = pl.yPos + pl.height;
        p.jumping = false;
        p.hitPlatform = true; // flag a platform has been hit
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#score {
  color:white;
  font-size:35px;
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Square Stairs™</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000">
  <div id="score">SCORE:</div>
  <br><br><br> <!-- line breaks to move canvas away from SO title bar that gets in the way when switching to full page mode -->
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border:3px solid #fff"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain this better, I am not sure how to implement it into my code

Comment: I implemented a possible version, I also went into some detail above it.  If you have any more questions about it, let me know. Thanks.